# Movies are corrupted/ending in the middle

Tags: video, media-player-classic, ac3, ffdshow

I watch movies in Media Player Classic Home Cinema.

This is the third movie that the same issue happens. In the middle of it, the movie stops. When I go see what happened, it just jumps to the end while it's in the middle. It's always on the same moment of the video.

First time it happened I believed the file was corrupted. The second time was bad luck. Now I know it's not corrupted files, it's something with MPC-HC or some plugin.

For AVC I use ffdshow's libavc. For audio it's AC3filter.

The strange thing is that it always happens on the same moment on each video, but I rechecked on the torrent and the file isn't corrupt.

Any idea?

Comment: Play the movie with a different player....http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Comment: Are you streaming? If so try down-loading first.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm more than 90% sure that the issue was because of PC's standby mode + the move being on a NAS. I think I left MPC opened and sent PC to standby, and somehow MPC was unable to recover network connection after it was powered on back.